# Android RecyclerView - Unresolved reference to getBindingAdapter()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` implementation in my app and I wanted a reference to the adapter which bound this view holder. As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapter()), I see a `getBindingAdapter()` in the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` which returns a reference to the adapter. However, when I do `this.getBindingAdapter()`, I get a compile error saying `Unresolved reference: getBindingAdapter`. `this` in the above code references a direct sub-class of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. I'm not sure what did I do wrong?

```
class VideoViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: WidgetVideoViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    // Other methods here...

    override fun checkIfValid(video: Video) {
        this.getBindingAdapter() // Compile error here
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): VideoViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            return VideoViewHolder(WidgetVideoViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is a VideoViewHolder and not a RecyclerView.ViewHolder. You will need to cast it to a RecyclerView.ViewHolder and then call the `getBindingAdapter()`.

Comment: @RayHunter But VideoViewHolder is already a subclass of RecyclerView.ViewHolder, so I should be able to call it if it is there! And as per the docs, it is a a public method but ironically I don't see it in the source code either. :P

Comment: What version of recycler view are you using? Oddly I do not see the method in the current stable release 1.1.0 but do see it in 1.2.0-alpha06.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Yes I'm using 1.1.0. Is there any doc which says this (something like added in 1.2.0) or do we need to open source code and check?

Comment: Not that I can see. In the Android Platform documentation they say what API level a class/method was added in and even allow you to select a particular API level to browse the documentation in. I do not see anything similar when browsing androidx documentation and am surprised something in an alpha release only would be in their main public documentation.

Comment: Even I was under the assumption that alpha API changes can't be there in the docs, hence didn't bother to look at all. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out :)